# How can I have editor templates for Nullable<DateTime> as well as DateTime?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

What do name the template files is my main question? If if have `@model DateTime?` in one, can I use it for straight DateTime?

MS seems to have dropped the ball with editors for some nullables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward to set-up

Have `@model DateTime?` as the model.  Name the file `DateTime.cshtml`.

Depending on how you plan on rendering your inputs, you may have to have some logic in the template along the lines of

```
@if (Model == null)
{
  // do this
} 
else 
{
  // do that
}
```